# Making < div > appear in a random order and in random position

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

I'm trying to create a minigame using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. It is structured as a table 4x4. Every row of my table is memorized inside a `<section>` tag. Each `<section>` cointains 4 `<div>`s. I would like to make one random element of the table appear when I hit a button. Also, it would be great to have elements appear in a random order.

Here's part of my code:

```
<section class="oggettoElements">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="11"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="21"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="31"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="41"></i>
</section>
<section class="oggettoElements">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="12"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="22"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="32"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="42"></i>
</section>
<section class="oggettoElements">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="13"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="23"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="33"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="43"></i>   
</section>
<section class="oggettoElements">
    <i class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="14"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="24"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="34"></i>
    <i class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="44"></i>
</section>
```

So, my goal is: have a function to make one element at a time appear (I'll call it with an onClick attribute in a button). The element will be a random one from the table.

Can anybody help me? Thank you very much

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. Surely we can help you with **your** code, but we are not a service that creates code on demand. Please do research on how to do each of your tasks and then make an effort to build it. Then if you get stuck there is a lot more we can do.

Comment: Hi @EmielZuurbier. Of course you're not... I'm sorry if it seemed I was asking you that. I was hoping maybe you could suggest something like "try with this tool..." or "see this link with similar contents". I really don't know where to start. I've been looking online and thinking about a solution for a few days now, but everything I found didn't seem to work yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following inline code snippet implements the random apparition of grid elements and demonstrates some (hopefully) helpful concepts:

- Css-based layout using the `display` property for tabular layout;
- Content centering with Css property `display: flex`;
- Programmatic access to DOM element(s) using `document.querySelector(...)`, `document.querySelectorAll(...)`;
- A DOM NodeList is not an array. Similar surprises abound, reference docs & specs are your friend. The docs, not YouTube videos ...

Remember that `id` attribute values must not be numeric. Avoid over-optimizing - the selection of elements not yet on display is extremely primitive, the more elements are visible, the more attempts are needed to find a hidden element. However, in response to interaction with slow humans, efficiency is not an issue ... ;)

```js
let b_allVisible = false
  ;
  
function showme ( eve ) {
    let e_chosen
      , n_c
      , n_r
      ;
      
    b_allVisible = !(
      Array
        .from(document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="c-"]'))
        .some ( (pe_grid) => { return pe_grid.style.visibility !== 'visible'; } )
    );
    
    if (b_allVisible) {
      document.getElementById('showme').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
      do {
          n_c = 1 + Math.floor( 4 * Math.random() ); 
          n_r = 1 + Math.floor( 4 * Math.random() ); 
          e_chosen = document.querySelector(`#c-${n_c}${n_r}`);
              // Here (referencing an element by their id), 'document.getElementById(`c-${n_c}${n_r}`)' can also be used.
              // Note the absence of the selector marker '#' for ids
      } while ( e_chosen.style.visibility === 'visible' );

      e_chosen.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
} // showme
```

```css
body > section {
    display:    table;
    padding:    20px;
}
section.oggettoElements {
    display:    table-row;
}
section.oggettoElements > div {
    display:    table-cell;
    border: solid 1px black;
    height: 30px;
    width:  30px;
    visibility: hidden;
}
section.oggettoElements > div > div {
    display:            flex;
    height:             30px;
    align-items:        center;
    justify-content:    center;
}
div > span {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center
}
```

```html
<section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
        <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="c-11"><div><span>01</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="c-21"><div><span>02</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="c-31"><div><span>03</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="c-41"><div><span>04</span></div></div>
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
        <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="c-12"><div><span>05</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="c-22"><div><span>06</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="c-32"><div><span>07</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="c-42"><div><span>08</span></div></div>
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
        <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="c-13"><div><span>09</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="c-23"><div><span>10</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="c-33"><div><span>11</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="c-43"><div><span>12</span></div></div>   
    </section>
    <section class="oggettoElements">
        <div class="far fa-newspaper oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #0000FF;" id="c-14"><div><span>13</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-glass-alt oggetto"    draggable="true" style="color: #008000;" id="c-24"><div><span>14</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-wine-bottle oggetto"       draggable="true" style="color: #FFD700;" id="c-34"><div><span>15</span></div></div>
        <div class="fas fa-apple-alt oggetto"         draggable="true" style="color: #8B4513;" id="c-44"><div><span>16</span></div></div>
    </section>
</section>
<button id="showme" name="showme" onclick="showme()">Show Me!</button>
```

Comment: Hi @collapsar! Thank you very much for helping me and for your precious explanation! You really made my day!